# How to open this program on a window?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, joptionpane

Can anyone help me with my if and else statements? It's only saying "Exit Goodbye" whenever I input something, which should only happen when I enter -0.  My teacher is gone for the week, so I don't have anyone to ask for help.

```
package game;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class GameFrame {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
     // num1 - Variable to store the first value
       // num2 - Variable to store the second value
       // answer - Variable to accept user input
        int num1, num2, answer=0;

        /*@reader - The reader which accepts user input*/
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new     InputStreamReader(System.in));
        /*@quit - Variable used to exit the program*/
        boolean quit = false;
        /*@generator - The Random number generator*/
        Random generator = new Random();

        while (quit == false)
        {
          //Generate First Random Number between 1-100
          num1 = generator.nextInt(100);
          //Generate First Random Number between 1-100
          num2 = generator.nextInt(100);
          //Displays the math equation
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,num1+ "+" + num2 + " = ");
          //Accepts the user's input and converts it to int value
          int number = Integer.parseInt(input);
          //Lets assume if user enters -99, it means they want to exit the program
          if (answer == -0)
          {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exit Program: Good Bye!\n");
              quit = true;
          }else if (answer == (num1+num2))
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Correct Answer!\n");
          else{
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect Answer\n");
    }
}
 }
}
```

Comment: Trying to transfer a console program to a GUI program is not an easy task if you've never made a GUI program before. You need to learn about event-driven programming. I suggest you have a look at the [Swing tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that when you edit a question(post), don't overwrite the original question, as this may invalidate answers answered prior to the edit. Instead, below the original post, just write **EDIT** and append the edited content to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to transfer a console program to a GUI program is not an easy task if you've never made a GUI program before. You need to learn about event-driven programming. I suggest you have a look at the [Swing tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Some tips though. It you want a "semi-gui" program. You can just use `JOptionPane`s for the input. Say you want to get an number input. You would do something like this

```
String numberString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a Number");
int number = Integer.parseInteger(numberString);
```

once you do the first line, an input pane automatically pops up. asking for an input. The result is a String, so you *have* to parse it to get a number.

Also if you just want to *diplay* a message, just use

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
```

You can do that do display some result. In the above case when you just want to show a message, you don't need to make it equal to anything. So instead of the `System.out.println()`s, you can just use the `JOPtionpane.showMesageDialog()` and instead of `reader.readLine()`, you would use `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()`

Try it out and come back if you're stuck.

---

Also see the [documentation for JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) to see what other possible popup dialogs there are.

Comment: Thanks dude. It worked partially, but now whenever I input something, the result is just saying "Exit! Goodbye!", one of my if statements.  But that's only supposed to happen whenever I enter -0

Comment: while (quit == false)

         {

           //Generate First Random Number between 1-100

           num1 = generator.nextInt(100);

           //Generate First Random Number between 1-100

           num2 = generator.nextInt(100);

           //Displays the math equation

         String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,num1+ "+" + num2 + " = ");

           //Accepts the user's input and converts it to int value

           int number = Integer.parseInt(input);

           //Lets assume if user enters -99, it means they want to exit the program

Comment: if (answer == -0)

           {

           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exit Program: Good Bye!\n");

               quit = true;

           }else if (answer == (num1+num2))

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Correct Answer!\n");
         
           else{

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect Answer\n");

Answer (score 0):

Try This this is working am run on my computer

```
  /**
  *
 * @author sandeepk
 */
  import java.io.BufferedReader;
  import java.io.InputStreamReader;
  import java.util.Random;

  import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

  public class GameFrame {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
 // num1 - Variable to store the first value
    // num2 - Variable to store the second value
    // answer - Variable to accept user input
    int num1, num2, answer = 0;

    /*@reader - The reader which accepts user input*/
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    /*@quit - Variable used to exit the program*/
    boolean quit = false;
    /*@generator - The Random number generator*/
    Random generator = new Random();

    while (quit == false) {
        //Generate First Random Number between 1-100
        num1 = generator.nextInt(100);
        //Generate First Random Number between 1-100
        num2 = generator.nextInt(100);
        //Displays the math equation
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, num1 + "+" + num2 + " = ");
        //Accepts the user's input and converts it to int value
        int number = Integer.parseInt(input);
        //Lets assume if user enters -99, it means they want to exit the program
        System.out.println("number  " + number);
        if (number == 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exit Program: Good Bye!\n");
            quit = true;
        } else if (number == (num1 + num2)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct Answer!\n");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect Answer\n");
        }
    }
}
 }



 if my code is run and you satisfy then please vote me thanks.
```